# Fixed dragging in Dismissible class

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using **Dismissible class** I created a listView.

Instead of completely closing each item in the list, *I want to partially drag it and keep it still.*

I have read the documentation but to no avail.

**Do you have an idea?**